# Routing nested resources to parent index path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm creating a messaging system in Rails, in a similar way to that of what Facebook has.

To make it easy to have conversation with each user, I nested users with messages resources:

```
  resources :messages do
    resources :users, only: [:show], :path => ''
  end
```

However, currently my `message_user_path` is in the following format

```
/messages/:message_id/:id
```

but what I need is for it to be **defaulted to messages index path, without message_id**

```
/messages/:id
```

Where `:id` is **User id, not  message id.** It seems I've tried everything, and I'm sure it's probably something really simple, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it!

Thank you for any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a Look at 2.7.2, I think it could help lead you to the answer. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Without a little more information on how you set up your models and the use case, I cant definitively say what you should do.  If you have any more information i'd be glad to help some more.

Comment: Hmm, that's correct, managed to do it with scoping both messages and users with shallow path and explicitly declaring the controller action to Messages show. Thanks for pointing me to right direction!